# Differential equation with reciprocal and constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation with a reciprocal and a constant:

$$ dx/dt =-\frac{a}{x}-b, $$

where $a$ is a positive constant and $b$ a nonnegative constant. I can solve this for $b=0$. Then (if this is allowed...)
$$x dx = -adt.$$
Integrating both sides and summing up the constants of integration gives
$$\frac{1}{2} x^2 = -at+C,$$
hence
$$x = \sqrt{2(-at+C)}. $$
Perhaps this is a rather elementary question, but how can this be solved for $b>0$? Since $1/x$ is not a well-behaved function, does this differential equation have an analytical solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shift all of the R.H.S in the denominator and put the $dt$ in the R.H.S to get 
$$\frac{dx}{\frac{-a}{x}-b}=dt$$
$\implies$
$$\int \frac{-xdx}{a+bx}=\int dt$$
$\implies$
$$\int \frac{-bx-a+a}{a+bx}dx=bt+bC$$
$\implies$
$$-x+a\int \frac{dx}{a+bx}=bt+bC$$ 
Hence
$$-x+\frac {a}{b}\log_e |a+bx|=bt+C'$$
is the required solution.

Comment: And, once more, $x$ would be given in terms of Lambert function ! Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. I understand all your steps. Neat trick to multiply by $a$ and adding and subtracting $b$. Seems like this can only be solved numerically for $x$, but that should be easy with a computer.

Comment: You can also use the W function as Claude pointed out

Comment: I did a major edit, I had solved it wrongly, but now it's corrected (just so you know)

Comment: @Nikunj Can you show how writing it in terms of lambert W would work? I'm stuck with this $a$ term before the logarithm. My function becomes something like $-(a+bx)^ae^{-(a+bx)} = Ce^{b^2t}$. This is only a Lambert W function if $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*} 
  \int dt &= -\int \frac{dx}{\frac{a}{x}+b} \\
  t &=\int \frac{x\, dx}{a+bx} \\
    &=\int \left[ \frac{1}{b}-\frac{a}{b(a+bx)} \right] dx \\
    &=\frac{x}{b}-\frac{a}{b^{2}} \ln |a+bx|+C
\end{align*}

Comment: @Nikunji, breakdown into partial fractions first.

Comment: Your first approach was clearly wrong so that's why I asked, any way this one is correct!

Comment: @Nikunji, made a lot of typos while editing